# About residual sets and dense sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose $E\subset X$ is some subset of a (complete) metric space $X$. To each $p\in E$ we associate a small ball $B(p,\epsilon_p)$ centered at $p$, and we want to consider the union 
$$
\hat E:=\bigcup_{p\in E} B(p,\epsilon_p)
$$

**Question:** When $E$ is only a dense subset, then $\hat E$ may not be the total space. A counter example is that $E=\mathbb Q$ and $X=\mathbb R$. If we further require $E$ is residual, can we conclude $\hat E=X$? If not, any counter example?

Comment: +1 A very interesting question! I've worked quite a bit with various strengthenings of being a residual set, as well as with various density notions, and the type of union you're forming is not all that different from things I've dealt with, but off-hand I don't know the answer. I suppose that if I'm overlooking something obvious, or at least something I should have thought of, then I'll find out soon enough!

Comment: Suppose that $x \in X \setminus E$. I bet you can choose each $\varepsilon_p$ so that $B(p,\varepsilon_p)$ misses $x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

E.g. if $E$ is the set of irrationals in the reals (which is residual), we can take $r_p =|p|$ for 
all irrational $p$ and then $0 \notin \hat{E}$ for that those radii.

So there is no general guarantee that $\hat{E}  = X$; we can always avoid specific points of the complement if we so desire.

Comment: This is an "overlooking something obvious" thing that I thought might happen, but now the natural problem arises of determining some upper limits (cardinality, density, etc.) that exist when $E$ is, say, $c$-dense in the space or has full measure or is residual. It's easy to get any isolated set for certain choices of such "big" sets. What about any scattered set, or any countable set, etc.